# 特定のViewを固定する

Tags: objective-c

画面上の特定のViewを固定するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
例えば下から順に`ScrollView`、`ImageView`、`UIView`と重ねていたとします。この`UIView`は半透明です。そして画面をピンチイン・アウトすると`ImageView`を拡大縮小するようにしたいです。しかしこのとき半透明の`UIView`も一緒に拡大縮小されてしまいます。`ImageView`だけを拡大縮小させるにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
色々と考えてみたのですが、ピンチイン・アウトの際に`UIView`を固定できないかと考えてみました。しかし調べてみたもののやり方がわかりません。
もし特定のViewを固定する方法があれば教えていただきたいです。また、僕の考えた解決策より良い方法があれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

ImageViewのproperty　autoresizesSubviewsをNoにすれば、いいのでは。あるいは、UIViewのautoresizeMaskをNoにするか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ImageViewのautoresizesSubviewsをNoにしたり、UIViewのautoresizeMaskをNoにしてみたのですが、UIViewとImageViewが一緒に拡大縮小されてしまいました。

Comment: @kojiharu じゃ、ピンチイン・ピンチアウトするときにジェスチャーレコグナイザー使っていると思いますが、それは、どこに貼りつけてます？

Comment: ジェスチャーレコグナイザーは使っておらず、ピンチイン・アウトはScrollViewの機能で実現しています。デリゲートメソッドのviewForZoomingInScrollViewを使っています。

Answer (score 1):

`UIImageView`インスタンスと、`UIView`インスタンスの、親子関係（`superview`と`subview`の関係）をやめれば、`UIImageView`だけズームします。
おそらく「いやいや、親子関係でなければいけないんだよ」ということなんだろうと思いますが、もしそうなら、その必然性を、納得いくように説明いただければと思います。

Comment: Storyboardエディタでビューをビューの上にドラッグするだけでそれらが勝手に親子になってしまうので、ビュー階層を崩す操作方法が分かれば良いのかもしれません。

Comment: @ura14h いや、それが今回私も初めて知ったのですが、Storyboard上では、`UIImageView`にSubviewを乗せることができないようになってるんです（Xcode 6ですくなくともXcode 6ではそうなってる）。なので、質問者さんは、意図してプログラムで、`UIImageView`に`UIView`を`addSubview:`していると読み取れるのです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。[self.scrollView addSubview:ImageView]とし、[self.view addSubview:UIView]としてImageViewとUIViewの親子関係を切ったのですが、そうするとズームがされなくなりました。恐らく一番上に重なっているUIViewをタッチしておりScrollViewに触れてないからなのではないかと思います。一番上にUIViewがあるのに下のImageViewをUIViewに触れてズームさせることはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: この情報は参考になりますか? http://qiita.com/uin010bm/items/f066d7dfa5c5a6da903a

Comment: @ura14h さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。リンク先の方法を試してみると一番上のUIViewはそのままで下のImageViewを拡大縮小することができました！大変うれしいです！誠にありがとうございます！